# How to filter Stack OverFlow questions depending upon the tags which I prefer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Let me know if this is duplicate of any other existing thread and route me to the original post. I am using the SO for nearly around 2 months.

Currently I am working on one tech( JQuery DataTable) and searching all over the google ans SO for the answers that can solve my issues. In this learning process I am trying to look for other users who post their questions on `DataTables` but I did not find a way to filter the SO questions so that I can view only those question which are for the required topic( like java, sql or datatables in my case). I have added '`datatables`' as my fav tag to my profile and added 13 other tags in the 'ignore tags' section but still I can see lot more questions with other new tags which I do not want to add them all to my Ignore tag section as because I will end up adding 30+ or more tags.

So can come one tell if there is way I can filter the question based on the tags that I can only view those question which I preferred? or there is way I should give feedback to SO to add this feature(if it is not present now) in future.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, adding favorite tags is not going to completely filter your feed. Tag filtering can be achieved by clicking on any tag or inserting `[tag_name]` into the search bar (on top of your screen).

You can also add tags that you don't want to see by preceding it with a `-`. For example, if you want `datatables` but not `angularjs`, just search for:

```
[datatables] -[angularjs]
```